# ActionBarSherlock: open submenu with menu button

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, submenu

I'm using ActionBarSherlock-4.1.0-0 and I would like to open my submenu in the Actionbar with the hardware menu button. I'm planing an update and in my old version I used the "normal" menu. I'd like to help users to get used to the new design.

I got the submenu and the main-menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater i = getSupportMenuInflater();
    i.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = (SubMenu) menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_submenu);
    Menu mainMenu = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and I got a listener to the hardware menu button:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            // TODO: expand submenu from actionbar
            return true;

        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I couldn't find a method or anything else to call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I try this solution from Frederik with android actionbar and I run into the problem that the submenu opens and closes immediately. Changing to onKeyUp solved this issue.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && optionsMenu != null && optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.sub_menu) != null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "performIdentifierAction");
            optionsMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.sub_menu, 0);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

I do check if `optionsMenu != null && optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.sub_menu) != null` because of compatibility issues with older Android versions without actionbar. This isn't nessesary if you use ActionBarSherlock for all versions.

Comment: It should be ACTION_UP, not ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved the issue

```
mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(id_of_menu_item, 0);
```

So in your case I would imagine it would be like this

```
private Menu mainMenu; // local variable for menu

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater i = getSupportMenuInflater();
    i.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    SubMenu subMenu = (SubMenu) menu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_submenu);
    mainMenu = menu; // store the menu in an local variable
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            SubMenu subMenu = (SubMenu) mainMenu.findItem(R.id.actionbar_submenu);
            mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(subMenu.getItem().getItemId(), 0);

            return true;  
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

In short:

- Store the menu in a local variable
- Use that variable to look for the sub menu
- Use that variable to call the `performIdentifierAction` method

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but when I implement your solution, then I get a java.lang.NullPointerException at line mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(subMenu.getItem().getItemId(), 0);. The subMenu object is null, any advice?

Comment: The idea is that you need to find the item id of your submenu and use that. What is the id of you sub menu id? (The r.id.[theid])? What I do in my implementation is to store the MenuItem in in a local var and use that to do: getItemId().

Answer (score 4):

I always got a NullPointerException with the solution of Fredrik Sundmyhr, then I changed a few things and it worked. Here's my solution:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
                SubMenu subMenu = mainMenu.getItem(2).getSubMenu();
                mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(subMenu.getItem().getItemId(), 0);

                return true;  
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
```